# Rules in DROOLS are not fired

Tags: maven, drools

I have 2 simple rule in DROOLS to test whether the rule is fired or not. This is The rules:

```
package rule2
import com.SBVR.carrental.model.Rental

rule "Your First Rule"
    when
        Rental(  )
    then
        System.out.println("Rental exist");
end

rule "Your Second Rule"
    when
    //conditions
    then
    System.out.println("Second rule");
end
```

I'm also adding eventListener to my kieSession so i would know whether a rule is fired or not, and this is the code that i use to fire rules:

```
KieServices service = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = service.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession session= kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules2");
        session.addEventListener(new RuleRuntimeEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Object inserted \n"
                        + event.getObject().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void objectUpdated(ObjectUpdatedEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Object was updated \n"
                        + "new Content \n" + event.getObject().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void objectDeleted(ObjectDeletedEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Object retracted \n"
                        + event.getOldObject().toString());
            }
        });

        session.addEventListener(new AgendaEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void matchCreated(MatchCreatedEvent event) {
                System.out.println("The rule "
                        + event.getMatch().getRule().getName()
                        + " can be fired in agenda");
            }

            @Override
            public void matchCancelled(MatchCancelledEvent event) {
                System.out.println("The rule "
                        + event.getMatch().getRule().getName()
                        + " cannot b in agenda");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent event) {
                System.out.println("The rule "
                        + event.getMatch().getRule().getName()
                        + " will be fired");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
                System.out.println("The rule "
                        + event.getMatch().getRule().getName()
                        + " has be fired");
            }

            @Override
            public void agendaGroupPopped(AgendaGroupPoppedEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void agendaGroupPushed(AgendaGroupPushedEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeRuleFlowGroupActivated(RuleFlowGroupActivatedEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterRuleFlowGroupActivated(RuleFlowGroupActivatedEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeRuleFlowGroupDeactivated(RuleFlowGroupDeactivatedEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterRuleFlowGroupDeactivated(RuleFlowGroupDeactivatedEvent event) {
            }
        });
        Rental mirrorRental = new Rental();
        session.insert(mirrorRental);
        session.fireAllRules();
        session.dispose();
```

Anf this is the result:

```
Object inserted 
com.SBVR.carrental.model.Rental@3d4ab141
The rule Your Second Rule can be fired in agenda
The rule Your Second Rule will be fired
Second rule
The rule Your Second Rule has be fired
```

My question is: The second rule is fired obviously because there's no conditions. The first rule have a simple condition to check whether the Rental is exist or not. and by the logs, it clearly shows that Rental is inserted into the rule engine. Why is the first rule not even fired?

Comment: Really weird. Are those the only 2 rules you have? Can you create another rule with a condition of `Object()` and see if it is triggered by the object you are inserting?

Comment: Yes i have tried using a third rule where the condition is only Car( ), and the third rule that i have just create is not even fired, like the first rule

Comment: But what about with `Object()`. I'm suspecting you may have a conflict in your classpath and your model is loaded twice. Try to write a rule with `Object()` to see if it gets fired or not.

Comment: wow. it's fired. how to check the conflict in the classpath? and how do i know the model is loaded twice?

Comment: Check that you don't have duplicated jars containing your model in the classpath